# Gnome Disk Utility, option to format mbr ? does option "overwrite existing data with zeroes" check bad sector like format in windows

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, usb, hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

When use gnome-disk-utility, after choose:

[image]

then choose

[image]

Does the option `Compatible with all systems and devices (MRB/DOS)` format MBR (I mean wipe out old MBR and write new MBR in the first sector)? And does this option will kill MBR virus? I ask this since I'm not sure is there possibility that when my usb/hard drive already has MRB and gnome-disk-utility just reuse it.

Another question, beside overwriting zeros into usb/hard drive for erasing data, does the option `overwrite existing data with zeroes (slow)` (in above picture) check bad sector like format in windows? If so, does gnome-disk-utility try to repair bad sectors?

**EDIT :** my question is about confirming some functions of gnome-disk-utility, not about how to do this functions by other tools.

Comment: "Overwrite data with zeroes" has nothing to do with MBR. It will overwrite the user data, making it harder to recover. If you want to overwrite just the MBR with zeroes, use dd: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`.

Comment: First, how big is your HDD? Is your computer UEFI? Will this be a data disk, or a system disk? That will determine whether MBR or GPT partition table is best for you. Writing zeros is mostly just to wipe data, not bad block, but it may do some along the way? I can give you the proper procedure if you wish to truely bad block the disk after the new partition table.